# Incrementing ArrayElement Parameters based on previous ELEMENTS

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist

I am new to java but have been playing with array-lists and am now stuck.

I have an array list created off a class called Car with three parameters one of which is called **times moved**.

Main Class

```
public class GarageTester {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
   // create Bank object
   Garage bashimGarage = new Garage() ;


  // create Scanner object associated with input file
  Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new 
   File("C:\\Users\\jamison\\Desktop\\GarageData.txt")) ;

  // read BankAccount data from file, create objects, and add to list

   while ( fileScan.hasNextLine())      // while not eof
   {

     String fullText = fileScan.nextLine();
     // Split the acquired string into 2 based on the whitespace
     String[] splitText = fullText.split("\\s+");
     // String before whitespace split
     String licensePlate = splitText[0];
     // String after whitespace split
     String status = splitText[1];
     // create Car object
     Car newCar = new Car(licensePlate, status , 0) ;  
     // add to list   
     bashimGarage.addCar( newCar ) ;   

   }


  /*
    *Calculates the number of times car was temporary moved before departure
  */
  bashimGarage.carDepart();


  /*
    *Prints list of car license plates
    * Admits or declines a car to the garage
    * Prints if a car departs the Garage
    * When a car departs also prints the number of times it was moved
  */
   bashimGarage.moveCarInGarage();
```

Car Class

```
public class Car {

   private String licensePlate;    // License Plate Number
   private String status ;         // Status: Arivved or Departed
   private int moved;              /* How many times the car 
                                  got moved out of the garage
                                  */


public Car ( String licenseNum, String carStatus , int timesMoved)
 {   
    licensePlate = licenseNum ;
    status = carStatus ;
    moved = timesMoved;
 }


public String getLicenseNum()
{   
  return licensePlate;
}


public String getStatus()
{   
  return status;
}



 public int getTimesMoved()
{   
  return moved;
}



public int setTimesMoved(int times){
    moved = moved + times;
    return moved;
  }

}
```

Garage Class

```
public class Garage {
   private ArrayList<Car> list ;  // a list of BankAccount objects
   public int maxCars = 10;       // max number of cars allowed in garage
   public int currentCars = 0;    // current number of cars in garage


public Garage()
{
  list = new ArrayList<Car>() ;
}


 public void addCar(Car newCar)
 {
   list.add(newCar) ;        // calls "add" method of ArrayList class
 } 


  public void carDepart() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Car current = list.get(i);   // get next car
    if (current.getStatus().equals("DEPART")) {
        int pos = list.indexOf(current);

        for (int j = 0; j < pos; j++) {
            list.get(j).setTimesMoved(1 + current.getTimesMoved());
        }

        list.remove(i);
        return;
     }

    }
 }



  public void moveCarInGarage()
  {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ )
    {
     Car current = list.get( i ) ;   // get next car
     if (current.getStatus().equals("ARRIVE"))
     {
         currentCars++; //Increments current # of cars in garage

       if (currentCars <= 10) // Checks if there is space in garage
       {
           //Prints license plate and arrival status to screen
           System.out.println("Car with license plate" + 
            current.getLicenseNum() + " has arrived "
                   + "and been moved into the garage");
       }
       else 
       {
           // Prints garage is full to screen
           System.out.println("The garage is full at this " +
           "time so come back later");
        }
     }
      else  
      {

         currentCars--; // Decrements current # of cars in garage
         /* 
         Prints license plate, departure status, 
         and number of times moved to screen
         */
         System.out.println("Car with license plate" + 
           current.getLicenseNum() + " is departing and has been moved " 
                 + current.getTimesMoved() + " times" );

       }
    }
 }
```

I am reading input of a file that is supposed to be like a garage and says if a car is **"Arriving"** or **"Departing"**

I am trying to write a code using an if statement that says if the status is "Departing" then the current element gets deleted the all elements in front of it add one to their **"times moved parameter"**

The part I am stuck on is the one where, based on the element getting deleted, all the elements in front of it in the array list add one to their **"times moved"** parameter.

I came up with this but it does not seem to work as when I call the 2nd method it always says 0 for times moved.

```
public void carDepart()
   {
     for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ )
        {
         Car current = list.get( i ) ;   // get next car
            if (current.getStatus().equals("DEPART"))
            {
              int pos = list.indexOf(i);

                for ( int j = 0 ; pos < j ; j++)
                {
                 current.setTimesMoved(1 + current.getTimesMoved());
                }

                 list.remove(i);
                 return;
          }

       }  
    }
```

Second method

```
    public void moveCarInGarage()
    {
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++ )
    {
       Car current = list.get( i ) ;     // get next car
       if (current.getStatus().equals("ARRIVE"))
     {
         currentCars++;

       if (currentCars <= 10) 
       {
           System.out.println("Car with license plate" + 
            current.getLicenseNum() + " has been moved into the garage");
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println("The garage is full at this " +
           "time so come back later");
       }
   }
     else 
     {
         currentCars--;
         System.out.println("Car with license plate" + 
           current.getLicenseNum() + " is departing and has been moved " 
                 + current.getTimesMoved() + " times" );
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First method, line 8.
Why are you trying to extract `pos` when you already have it in `i`. `int pos = list.indexOf(i);` will give -1.

Also, in this loop

```
for ( int j = 0 ; pos < j ; j++)
    {
          current.setTimesMoved(1 + current.getTimesMoved());
    }
```

You are always pointing to the same element in the arraylist.

Instead, you may want to program it like the following:

```
for ( int j = 0; j<i; j++)
    {
          Car car = list.get(j);
          car.setTimesMoved(1 + car.getTimesMoved());
    }
```

Comment: My logic was that when it first hits an element with the status depart it gets its index and then scans all the elements previous to that index and increments timesMoved by 1. I am not 100% sure what you mean by extract post when you already have it as I never tried to get the index before? Sorry if I sound abit lost

Comment: Oh. So you want to increment the previoys cars. I'll modify.

Comment: By extracting I meant that since you are iterating using loop variable `i`, wont `i` be the current index. Ou dont need to explicitly extract position of current index.

Comment: I understand now Sand provided a good example but even with the edited code it still gives 0 for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You had below issues in your method,

- First you were getting a index of an integer instead of the object.
- Your inner for loop condition was wrong.
- You were always increment the values of the current object instead of
  the previous ones.

I have corrected them in your method. Use below one,

```
public void carDepart() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Car current = list.get(i);   // get next car
            if (current.getStatus().equals("DEPART")) {
                /* You can remove below line and replace pos with i in your inner loop. 
                Since the current object position will be same as i */
                int pos = list.indexOf(current);

                for (int j = 0; j < pos; j++) {
                    list.get(j).setTimesMoved(1 + current.getTimesMoved());
                }

                list.remove(i);
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: When running the program it still says moved 0 times after running the 2nd method. Let me edit the code to include more information

Comment: I added more code as I am still getting 0 and am guessing it might be a bug somewhere else now

Comment: Main method added

Comment: Well its working correctly. If you replace the first print inside `moveCarInGarage` method with this `System.out.println("Car with license plate" + current.getLicenseNum() + " has moved " + current.getTimesMoved() + " times");` you should see its printing the times correctly. Maybe you need to think about your conditions?

Comment: The logic seems to be correct everywhere but it still always says 0 any idea why? Also why would I replace the first print statement if the first statement is for "ARRIVED" and the else would be depart